# Does mysql comes with the default installation?

Tags: mysql

I have checked that I have mysql installed. Does it comes with the default installation ?
I dont remember I have installed it.

Installed files : mysql server core 5.1,mysql client core, mysql common ,virtuoso minimal and open source.

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will be installed if you pick certain server roles during installation, like the LAMP role (Linux Apache MySQL PHP).

Comment: Hm well ! I have lamp but it is not installed from repos.